# Tried to remove apostrophes from String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to replace all apostrophes which were not surrounded by letters with a whitespace. For cases like `it's`, the apostrophe would not be replaced.

I have tried this:

```
str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z](')", " ")
   .replaceAll("(')[^a-zA-Z]", " ");
```

However, there was still some cases that could not work, and I also believed there should be a more elegant way to do that. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Unfortunately whatever you do, you'll remove some apostrophes you shouldn't. For example in words like `ol'` or `horses'`.

Comment: @biziclop Could you please be more specific? If there was no letters behind `ol'` and `horses'`, these apostrophes are supposed to be eliminated.

Comment: @WangNick Take a look at these [Apostrophe rules](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp). Notice how there are actually many correct uses of apostrophes at the end of words.

Answer (score 1):

Regex: [`^'+|'+(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/rRaaFy/2) (flags: g, m)

Matches an apostrophe at the start of the input. Matches all apostrophes without a non-whitespace character coming after it. The `+` allows the previous token (`'`) to be repeated if possible.

If you have examples of apostrophes that are replaced by this but shouldn't be, just leave them in a comment and I'll see if I can amend.